# How to make ubuntu 22.04 faster

Tags: updates, 22.04

Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 system requirements are the same. But the problem is I didn't get the smooth performance of 20.04 in 22.04. It's too laggy. How can I fix this problem? How can I speed up my ubuntu 22.04 lts?
These are my PC specs:

**Processor**: Intel® Core™ i3-4000M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
**Ram**: 6.0 GiB
**Graphics**: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
**HDD**: 1TB
**SSD**: No SSD

Comment: *What* is slow?

Comment: You have not provided any information about your computer? Is it old? Does it have enough RAM? Is the OS installed in an SSD or a HDD? In any case you may want to try [turning off animation](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/05/disable-animations-in-ubuntu-22-04) if you have an old computer.

Comment: An i3-M with 6GB and HD4600 is surely at the very low end of the spectrum.

Comment: thats my machine, I have 16GB though, works very well. but 22.04.1 has become a pain