# How to make Ubuntu 22.04 Faster?

Tags: nvidia, startup, startup-applications

I have referred this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407981/how-to-make-ubuntu-22-04-faster) but never found any solutions that fixed the issue.

I am running a dual boot (Windows 11 & Ubuntu 22.04) on my Legion i5(2022 model). Out of these operating system Ubuntu is running very Slow. The main issue being

1. Boot Time is Average even after installing the system on SSD, There is noticeable delay in logging in after entering the password(The system freeze for sometime).
2. Delay in opening Applications ( web browsers, etc)
3. High battery consumption when switching to dedicated graphics with NVIDIA drivers (so I am using the integrated graphics for longer battery backup)

**Edit** :

**result of :** `systemd analyze blame`

```bash
jishnu@Legion:~$ systemd-analyze blame
29.606s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-eae532fe\x2da4b8\x2d44e0\x2db90d\x2d71d468e55dc1.service
16.329s plymouth-quit-wait.service
11.779s gpu-manager.service
 6.605s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 3.718s docker.service
 1.678s snapd.service
 1.111s mysql.service
 1.009s fwupd.service
  768ms udisks2.service
  721ms snapd.seeded.service
  600ms dev-loop6.device
  595ms dev-loop5.device
  592ms dev-loop7.device
  591ms dev-loop4.device
  586ms dev-loop3.device
  575ms dev-loop1.device
  574ms dev-loop2.device
  574ms dev-loop0.device
  504ms dev-nvme0n1p6.device
  353ms containerd.service
  321ms accounts-daemon.service
  320ms bluetooth.service
  305ms user@1000.service
  304ms apport-autoreport.service
  293ms systemd-logind.service
  280ms ModemManager.service
  258ms e2scrub_reap.service
  243ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  240ms networkd-dispatcher.service
  218ms power-profiles-daemon.service
  209ms home.mount
  198ms dev-loop40.device
  197ms dev-loop39.device
  196ms dev-loop45.device
  194ms dev-loop46.device
  194ms dev-loop37.device
  194ms dev-loop44.device
  192ms dev-loop47.device
  192ms dev-loop41.device
  190ms dev-loop38.device
  190ms dev-loop43.device
  189ms dev-loop21.device
  188ms update-notifier-download.service
  188ms dev-loop42.device
  188ms dev-loop22.device
  186ms dev-loop23.device
  184ms dev-loop14.device
  184ms dev-loop28.device
  183ms dev-loop36.device
  182ms dev-loop25.device
  180ms dev-loop31.device
  179ms dev-loop29.device
  179ms dev-loop32.device
  179ms dev-loop27.device
  178ms dev-loop30.device
  177ms dev-loop16.device
  176ms snapd.apparmor.service
  176ms dev-loop33.device
  175ms dev-loop24.device
  174ms dev-loop20.device
  171ms dev-loop26.device
  171ms dev-loop19.device
  170ms dev-loop17.device
  167ms dev-loop18.device
  166ms dev-loop15.device
  165ms dev-loop35.device
  165ms dev-loop8.device
  164ms dev-loop34.device
  164ms dev-loop13.device
  162ms dev-loop11.device
  162ms dev-loop10.device
  160ms dev-loop12.device
  158ms dev-loop9.device
  156ms systemd-journald.service
  147ms systemd-timedated.service
  144ms systemd-modules-load.service
  141ms upower.service
  132ms switcheroo-control.service
  129ms systemd-resolved.service
  119ms apport.service
  113ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  112ms NetworkManager.service
  108ms systemd-oomd.service
  107ms systemd-udevd.service
  102ms avahi-daemon.service
  101ms snap-android\x2dstudio-124.mount
  100ms snap-android\x2dstudio-125.mount
   98ms snap-bare-5.mount
   97ms snap-brave-218.mount
   95ms snap-brave-220.mount
   94ms snap-code-120.mount
   93ms snap-code-122.mount
   91ms snap-core-14784.mount
   90ms snap-core-14946.mount
   88ms snap-core18-2714.mount
   86ms snap-core18-2721.mount
   86ms apparmor.service
   84ms snap-core20-1828.mount
   83ms snap-core20-1852.mount
   81ms snap-core22-547.mount
   80ms snap-core22-583.mount
   78ms snap-discord-150.mount
   78ms grub-common.service
   77ms snap-firefox-2391.mount
   76ms snap-firefox-2487.mount
   74ms systemd-journal-flush.service
   74ms snap-foxglove\x2dstudio-40.mount
   73ms snap-foxglove\x2dstudio-41.mount
   71ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount
   69ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-115.mount
   68ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount
   68ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
   68ms keyboard-setup.service
   66ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-56.mount
   65ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-65.mount
   64ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
   63ms preload.service
   63ms snap-hunspell\x2ddictionaries\x2d1\x2d7\x2d2004-2.mount
   62ms snap-mysql\x2dworkbench\x2dcommunity-10.mount
   61ms gdm.service
   60ms snap-notion\x2dsnap-16.mount
   59ms secureboot-db.service
   58ms snap-postman-184.mount
   57ms snap-snap\x2dstore-599.mount
   57ms cups.service
   56ms snap-snap\x2dstore-638.mount
   55ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   55ms snap-snapd-18357.mount
   54ms polkit.service
   54ms snap-snapd-18596.mount
   52ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-49.mount
   51ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-57.mount
   49ms snap-spotify-60.mount
   48ms snap-sublime\x2dtext-116.mount
   47ms binfmt-support.service
   47ms snap-sublime\x2dtext-118.mount
   45ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-4627.mount
   44ms systemd-rfkill.service
   44ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-4654.mount
   42ms snap-todoist-841.mount
   41ms snap-vlc-2344.mount
   39ms snap-vlc-3078.mount
   38ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d7\x2ddevel\x2dcore20-23.mount
   37ms rsyslog.service
   36ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d7\x2ddevel\x2dcore20-24.mount
   35ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime\x2dcore20-58.mount
   34ms modprobe@drm.service
   34ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime\x2dcore20-59.mount
   32ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
   31ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8837\x2dE5E6.service
   30ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   30ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   28ms dev-hugepages.mount
   27ms thermald.service
   26ms dev-mqueue.mount
   26ms packagekit.service
   25ms colord.service
   25ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   24ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0a2b2fa1\x2d8bae\x2d4c83\x2da428\x2d944be1e37aee.service
   23ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   22ms wpa_supplicant.service
   22ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
   21ms boot-efi.mount
   20ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   19ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   19ms plymouth-start.service
   19ms systemd-random-seed.service
   18ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72fa2c0c\x2d6e01\x2d40c2\x2d9359\x2d6dcdb926380e.swap
   18ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   17ms modprobe@configfs.service
   17ms alsa-restore.service
   14ms modprobe@fuse.service
   14ms systemd-sysusers.service
   14ms plymouth-read-write.service
   12ms systemd-backlight@leds:platform::kbd_backlight.service
   12ms kerneloops.service
   10ms systemd-sysctl.service
   10ms boot.mount
   10ms console-setup.service
    9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
    8ms systemd-update-utmp.service
    5ms ufw.service
    5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
    4ms rtkit-daemon.service
    4ms setvtrgb.service
    3ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
    3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    3ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
    3ms docker.socket
    3ms openvpn.service
    3ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
    2ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
    2ms modprobe@ramoops.service
    1ms snapd.socket
lines 134-195/195 (END)
```

**result of :** `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```bash
jishnu@Legion:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @48.225s
└─multi-user.target @48.224s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @31.894s +16.329s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @31.887s +5ms
      └─network.target @31.877s
        └─NetworkManager.service @31.765s +112ms
          └─dbus.service @31.757s
            └─basic.target @31.735s
              └─sockets.target @31.735s
                └─snapd.socket @31.733s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @31.700s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @31.523s +176ms
                      └─apparmor.service @31.436s +86ms
                        └─local-fs.target @31.401s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration.mnt.mount @44.796s
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @44.173s
                              └─swap.target @1.569s
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72fa2c0c\x2d6e01\x2d40c2\x2d9359\x2d6dcdb926380e.swap @1.546s +18ms
                                  └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-72fa2c0c\x2d6e01\x2d40c2\x2d9359\x2d6dcdb926380e.device @1.526s
```

How I tried to resolve the issue ? But these things didn't worked out for me and the issue s still prevails.

1. Keep my system updated.
2. Started using `bleachbit` for cleaning files in regular intervals
3. Used `preload` utility for preloading things.
4. Removed applications from the `StartUp App` list.

I would like to list the specification of my laptop

**Model** : **Lenovo Legion 5i (2020 model)** 
**Processor** : **Intel i5 10th gen** 
**Graphics**  : **NVIDIA GTX 1650 (dedicated) + Intel iris (integrated)** 
**RAM**       : **16 GB, DDR4,SODIM**
**Memory**    : **256 GB SSD + 1 TB HDD**

Comment: Twice you mention delay with no actual info. It takes a few seconds longer then you think it should, or an hour? What you think is slow others may not. How does the battery fit into this question? As written thee is not actual info can can be used to offer any help.

Comment: Have you installed the nvidia video driver, or are you using the nouveau video driver?

Comment: The delay in opening chromium is because it's now a snap.

Comment: probably using bleachbit? also switch all apps from snap to .deb packages just like @RonJohn said.

Comment: Some settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: For browsers, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1206153/124466 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: `Boot Time is Average even after installing the system on SSD` - Can you post the outputs of the commands `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`?

Comment: There is an almost 30 seconds checkdisk on some drive. Found out which drive this is, and check why it needs fsck on this for every boot. Check out this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/737383/40-seconds-fsck-of-some-drive-at-boot and this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239709/how-to-stop-filesystem-check-fsck-on-boot?rq=1